# sticky footer css fix

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I want the footer (with the adress and social icons) to be at the bottom of the page with NO extra after it (so no scroll down possible )

I also want it at the really bottom

It is working perfectly on this page [Working link](http://lebruloir.com/cafe-bistro/)

But when the content is not occupying full page height it is messing up...
like here : [At the bottom BUT adding some scrolling at the bottom](http://lebruloir.com/menu/)
I've looked around but can't seem to find the perfect solution, I need your knowledge

```
.sticky-footer-wrapper {
min-height:100%;
}

.push {
overflow:auto;
padding-bottom:200px;
}

footer {
position:relative;
margin-top:-200px;
height:30px;
clear:both;
}
```

html markup

```
<div class="sticky-footer-wrapper">


<div class="push"></div>

</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Typo? `</div`: missing `>`

Comment: @francoboy7 would a fixed forever footer do for you?

Comment: @Mr.Coder No it would not work. Thank for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

Set your footer to be position: fixed; with its bottom set to 0 Here is a sample of what you are looking for.
http://jsfiddle.net/t9Acp/

```
<footer>THis is a </footer>


   footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(51,51,51,.5);
    }
    body {
        height: 400em;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want any FIXED position as it will overlap on my content and be hidden by it sometime..

Comment: @francoboy7 so, set the opacity to low, and have it appear and disappear when the user hovers over it, heck you could even minimize it as well to.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you have a fixed height footer, set the bottom padding on the body element equal to the height of the footer, and then absolutely position the footer to the bottom of the page.

```
body { 
  padding-bottom:50px;
}

footer { 
  height:50px; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  bottom:0; 
}
```

You also don't need the empty element with class .push nor you would require a negative margin on the element with class sticky-footer-wrapper

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, it does not seem to work... thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're after this: [CSS sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

I've run into a similar issue before, all the CSS needs to be there.

EDIT: your content wrapper needs to have a negative margin set to the same height as the footer. If you use padding, it will only push it down further and result in more scrolling no matter how little content is in the page.

It should probably look something like this:

```
.sticky-footer-wrapper    {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -30px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
footer, .push {
    height:30px;
}
```

By setting the wrapper to fill the screen, then applying a negative margin the same height as the footer, it pushes the footer off-screen, then brings it back to the bottom of the page with the negative margin. Be careful with top and bottom padding, you'll need to add it to the negative margin of the wrapper, as it will contribute to the overall height.

Comment: well the rest is here I didn't wrote it down but it is here

Comment: It's best to show all your code, if people can't see the whole picture, they aren't able to help as much ;)